# How to search within a particular folder in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have folders in share shared folder. Is there any way to specify share to search for a particular file in particular folder of the shared folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've developed a solutions where you can search within a folder through the advanced search form: http://addons.alfresco.com/addons/alfresco-share-folder-search

It's free for download so you can look around how it's done.

In short: in 4.2.e you can send an extra param rootNode to the /slingshot/search repo webscript.

If you check the client side JavaScript in Share **components/search/search.js**

There is method **_buildSearchParams** The following params are send: `site={site}&term={term}&tag={tag}&maxResults={maxResults}&sort={sort}&query={query}&repo={repo}&rootNode={rootNode}&pageSize={pageSize}&startIndex={startIndex}`

So fill in the rootNode with a qnamePath or NodeRef and it will present the results of that folder.

Comment: I have sent an email to get the module. Thanks. Why this tool is not available for straight download?

Comment: We're setting up a website were in the future you can directly download these modules. It's not ready yet.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but there is no user friendly out of the box solution (I know of).

As admin, go to http://your-host.domain.name/share/page/console/admin-console/node-browser and execute a (fts-alfresco) search like the following:

```
PATH:"/app:company_home/app:shared//*" AND @cm\:name:"filename.txt"
```

This will find all files named "filename.txt" below the shared folder.

I guess you will have to customize the search UI if you want to offer that functionality in a user friendly fashion or to non admin users.

Further details are at http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Search#Path_Queries

Comment: I am planning to implement for non admin users can you provide me a link on it.

Comment: It very much depends where you want to implement this and how you want users to choose a path/multiple paths. Personally, I would consider extending the advanced search.

Answer (score 0):

For a possible implementation, I wrote a [long post about it on the alfresco community forum](https://forums.alfresco.com/comment/150461#comment-150461) .